# Laravel 5 helper to convert class name to dot case?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a helper to convert this:

\App\Models\MyModel

to this:

app.models.my_model

I have written my own helper for this, but it seems like a very common thing for the Laravel framework, so I thought I may be missing the built-in version.

The use case is to convert a class name to a view name so in a controller I can write something similar to:

```
return view(dot_case($classname));
```

Here is my version:

```
<?php

function dot_case($string)
{
    return str_replace('._', '.', snake_case(str_replace('\\', '.', $string)));
}
```

Comment: What's the use case? Where would you use this?

Comment: i'm not sure this is incredibly common, so writing it yourself is probably the correct way to go. are you looking to use this in your database for polymorphic relationships? if so, look into the 'morph map'

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I'd avoid any magic views from your models class name and insert it manually, or better yet, just set a public property on your model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    public $view = 'app.models.my_model';
}
```

-

```
// In your controller:

$model = MyModel::find(1);

return view($model->view);
```

This way there's no guesswork on which view is returned.